# Plus sign in VS Code Explorer Tree View

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to modify `VS Code` settings so that it uses the old fashion `[+]` and `[-]` signs instead of the arrows in the Explorer tree view -- see below?

[image]

Comment: There are several "icon theme" extensions that change those. E.g. I use "Material Icon Theme", and have "open/closed folder" icons instead. You can pick one of those, or make a custom one. Alternatively, it seems that the default icons are rendered with an icon font. You can try finding this font in VSC files and changing the icons with FontForge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will be quite easy, most icon packs i've seen use only hiding this icons.
After some investigation, I got that these icons are called 'chevron-up' and 'chevron-down' from font called [codicon](https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-codicons/dist/codicon.html). path to files which are used (`codicon.css` and `codicon.ttf`):

```
\vscode-master\src\vs\base\browser\ui\codiconLabel\codicon
```

so the idea is that you download this repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode
then edit css file to point to the font and icon you wish, or edit existing classes to make 'chevron-up' to be actially 'plus' sign:

```
.codicon-chevron-up:before {
    content: "\ea60"; // plus, "\eab7" - up sign
}
```

and finally, build vs code on local machine

note: did not test this myself, but it should give you right direction

Comment: Wow! I then have to build VS Code, huh! I wasn't expecting this to be that difficult.

Comment: @Sam yeah, a bit an overkill, but I could not find anything else. the easiest way is to go through a few icon packs and check which one you like the most.